# Trying to toggle an animation on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to expand a box on click, and once it is clicked again, I want to shrink it back to its normal state. this is my current code.

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px"
            }, "slow" );
        }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "50px",
            height: "50px"
            }, "slow" );
        });
});
```

the original size is 50px and i want it to toggle back and forth between 50 px and 200 px. Using this code, when the box is clicked, the box just disappears.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using jQuery 1.9+ and there is no jQuery [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event method, jQuery uses [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) display effect method and hides your element. `.toggle()` event method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and has been removed in jQuery 1.9.

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.height() == 200 ? '50px' : '200px';
    $this.stop().animate({
        width: val,
        height: val
    }, "slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q9UMA/